# MPICH2 Installation

Tags: mpi, mpich

Given the availability of a new workstation (Intell Xeon X5690, Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit) for numerical analysis of fluid dynamics models, I find it a shame not engage in parallel computing. So far, I have had no or little experience in this field.

What's the difference between MS-MPI and the latest release of MPICH suitable for Windows? I installed [MPICH 1.4.1](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/1.4.1p1/), but I cannot get a [test program](http://www.physics.sdsu.edu/~johnson/phys580/Parallel_computing1.pdf) to work on `Ifort`. How am I supposed to compile the program? Do I have to change `Ifort` configurations somehow to add the libraries of MPICH? Isn't there any good manual available online that could meet my needs?

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of questions in this one question, but it all boils down to one basic question: **How do I install MPI on Windows?**

MPICH has long since worked on Windows. The last version that supported it was 1.4.1p1 as you've found, but it doesn't have any support anymore from the MPICH developers so if you have trouble, you probably won't find much help. I haven't seen anyone on here step up to help with those questions so far.

MS-MPI is a good option if you want to use Windows. It's free to use and still has support directly from Microsoft. You'll have to read their documentation about how to set everything up correctly, but it's probably the right place to start if you want to use MPI on Windows.

Intel MPI also works on Windows, but it isn't free so you might not want to look at that right now.

Comment: Thanks Wesley. Actually Windows is a constraint that plays a major role in deciding the software I can use. All the other PC in the University Network run on Windows so I just turn to Linux when it comes to "private matters". Any other program you can suggest apart from those already mentioned? At the moment I just want to speed up the computations I little bit... I do not care about extreme optimization...

Comment: I don't know much about windows development. I'm an MPICH developer, not a windows user.

Comment: Install VirtualBox and a Linux VM therein and run MPICH there.